# Safe to delete contents of google cloudbuild bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

There are images there since a year ago, I am just not sure if they are used or if they are just temporarily stored there when the build happens. Do subsequent deployments override old images or do they just accumulate?

Comment: I personally use that small tool. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcr-cleaner

Comment: The images are immutable, you can safely delete one without breaking the others

Comment: Both of these suggestions solved it for me. Thank you.

Comment: I answered those comments to help the community ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images are immutable, you can safely delete one without breaking the others

In addition, to clean your images and to save space (and money) you can use a Google Cloud tool named [GCR cleaner](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcr-cleaner)